# I keep getting infinite loops in my subroutines, can someone help me?

Tags: python

I am trying to use subroutines and text files to record and output student data but i have an infinite loop for option 1,2 and 4 and have no idea how to fix it 
My code:

```
def displayMenu():
    print("1. save to new file")
    print("2. append to and existing file")
    print("3. calculate the average mark")
    print("4. display data")
    choice = input("enter choice")
    while int(choice) <1 or int(choice) >5:
        choice = input("pick a valid option")
    return choice
def saveToFile(a):
    studentMark = "0"
    studentName = input("enter a student name, type xxx when you are done")
    while studentName != "xxx":
        file = open ("studentMark.txt", "w")
        f = open("studentNames.txt", "w")

        studentMark = input("Enter mark:")
        f.write(studentName +"\n")
        file.write(studentMark + "\n")
        studentName = input("name")
        f.close()
        file.close()

def appendToFile(b):
    studentMark = "0"
    studentName = input("enter a student name, type xxx when you are done")
    while studentName != "xxx":
        file = open ("studentMark.txt", "a")
        f = open("studentNames.txt", "a")

        studentMark = input("Enter mark:")
        f.write(studentName +"\n")
        file.write(studentMark +"\n")
        studentName = input("name")
        f.close()
        file.close()
def average(c):
    total = 0.0
    length = 0.0
    average = 0.0
    file2 = open("studentMark.txt", "r")
    for line in file2:

        amount = float(studentmark)
        total += amount
        length = length + 1
    average = total / length
    print("Average mark:", average)
    file2.close()
def printstuff(d):
    o = open('output.txt', 'w')

    fh = open("studentNames.txt", "r")
    fh2 = open("studentMark.txt", "r")

    for line in (fh.readlines()):
        o.write(line.strip("\r\n") + "\t" + fh2.readline().strip("\r\n") + "\n")
    o.close()
    o = open("output.txt", "r")
    output = o.read()
    print(output)

    fh.close()
    fh2.close()
    o.close()

option = displayMenu()
while option != "5":
    if option == "1":
        saveToFile("write")
    elif option == "2":
        appendToFile("append")
    elif option == "3":
        average("mark")
    elif option == "4":
        printstuff("display")

print("quit")
```

The calculating averages section of my code is copy and edited from a forum so there may be some outdated code and stuff

Comment: `option` doesn't change in the loop. No wonder why it never ends

Comment: thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I created an infinite loop by not allowing the user to change their option